# Intelligent Binary Array Padding Algorithm: pd.Timestamp(parse($myDate)).value

Tags: python, arrays, date, time, matrix

How can I create an array that pads in 0s for 5-minute time ranges not occurring within the specified time range (in a format like 11:00A 12:30P) and 1s where a 5-minute time range falls within the specified time range.

What I'm thinking so far is just to start with

```
int(pd.Timestamp(parse($myDate)).value)
```

to get a number--not sure if you actually have to cast it as an integer though.

---

So, let's say I've got N date objects like this in Python. Let's say the desired function's name is `tmpdr()`. You'd take in dates like this

`tmpdr( d1 , d2 , d3 , ... , dN )`,

and the output would be an array--with 288 elements--like this:

```
[0,0,0,...,0,0,0,1,1,1,...,1,1,1,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,...,0,0,0]
```

Here, the ellipses represent the abstract idea of "the pattern continues like this"--just in case you didn't know or something. Anyway, I hope it's clear what's being asked: The 1's are representing the fact that "Hey, I'm minute-5 position number 67, and I'm in that time range!" Each position falling within the specified time range would be saying this--hopefully you follow this abstraction, and remember there will be multiple dates:

[image]

The times--what I'm calling dates for some reason--will never overlap; that is, we have the following:

```
d1 ∩ d2 ∩  ·  ·  ·  ∩ dn = {}
```

Here, ∩ stands for intersection, and `{}` stands for "empty set."

---

All start and stop times have minutes that are divisible by 5, so here is a list of some time examples in my database:

```
1:00P - 3:55P
8:30A - 12:00P
5:50P - 6:30P
```

There is no same-day-next-day overlapping, so no times like `11:00P - 3:00A`.

Comment: don't make a title like that, its confusing

Comment: I know, but I snagged you into my confusion! Mwa ha ha ha! No, but really, I think you're right. You have a better idea?